# some js not load with https in magento2

Tags: magento2, https

when i open my site with https some js missing. If i open with http it's working fine. I have installed SSl after redirect to https. I have also check `store->configuration->web->Secure url` but it's all set. See below js files are missing

> 1. sitepath/pub/static/frontend/emtheme/theme_name/en_CA/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js
> 2. sitepath/pub/static/frontend/emtheme/theme_name/en_CA/dropdownDialog.js
> 3. sitepath/pub/static/frontend/emtheme/theme_name/en_CA/equalElement.js
> 4. sitepath/pub/static/frontend/emtheme/theme_name/en_CA/domReady.js
> 5. sitepath/pub/static/frontend/emtheme/theme_name/en_CA/modal.js

Also same issue arrive in checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in system configuration --> web --> secure urls to allow ssl in front end.

If that's set to yes already, I usually cheat and set the insecure base URL to be prefixed with HTTPS:// (yes I know it says insecure) then that will make your site run under https exclusively and ensure all resources are loaded securely.

**cause:** Most browsers will block the loading of insecure content (e.g js, css) on a HTTPS session for security

Comment: Already  configuration --> web --> secure urls to allow ssl in frontend. Also i have set insecure url with https:// but still issue there.

Comment: Clear all caches including JS and images cache